# Comment lines in org-mode with clean view

Tags: org-mode

I want to insert a comment line between two top-level headings like this:

```
# first comment

* Top level headline
  * Second level
    * 3rd level
      some text
    * 3rd level
      more text

# second comment

* Another top level headline
```

Unfortunately the second comment shows up intended as part of the last 3rd level heading and it's impossible to unindent it:

```
# first comment

* Top level headline
  * Second level
    * 3rd level
      some text
    * 3rd level
      more text

      # second comment

* Another top level headline
```

Is it possible to override this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a design feature of Org-Mode.  There is no way to end a headline without starting a new one, so there is no way to return to top level between two headlines.

The closest method to display that sort of information between two top level headlines would be to use a non-exported headline as the comment.

```
* Second Comment                             :noexport:
```

This will not be folded into either of the other headlines (all the same level) and when exported nothing will appear at that level.  You can include any body to the comment (additional notes) as body to the headline, they will only appear if you expand the headline.

Answer (score 5):

Using the word `COMMENT` at the beginning of a heading prevents the entire subtree from being exported.

Keyboard shortcut: `C-c ;`.

Example:

```
* COMMENT Second Comment
```

Reference: http://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html